# SQL - Multiple register conditions query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following table structure:

```
ID       COMPANY       PROJECT      ACTIVITY     TYPE
1        A             1            A1.1         NORMAL
2        A             1            A1.2         NORMAL
3        A             1            A1.3         NORMAL
4        A             2            A2.1         DUMMY
5        A             2            A2.2         DUMMY
6        A             2            A2.3         DUMMY
7        A             3            A3.1         NORMAL
8        A             3            A3.2         DUMMY
9        A             3            A3.3         NORMAL
```

My objective is to retrieve the company and project where all activities (within the combination company x project) are dummies.

I wrote the SQL below:

```
SELECT COMPANY, PROJECT
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY COMPANY, PROJECT
HAVING TYPE = 'DUMMY'
```

However it brings not only Company A and Project 2 (which is the only that satisfies my condition), but also Company 3 Project 3 (hhich has only one DUMMY type).

Could you guys help me fixing the statement?

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are near to success. Make use of `MAX` and `MIN` functions.

```
SELECT  COMPANY, PROJECT
FROM    TABLE
GROUP   BY COMPANY, PROJECT
HAVING  MAX(TYPE) = MIN(TYPE) AND
        MAX(TYPE) = 'DUMMY'
```

Comment: Hi JW. Unfortunately it continues bringing company A / project 3 which is wrong. Do you have any other suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks JW. Unfortunately it does not work for MS Access in the same way... Weird. Do you have any other idea? Thanks!!!

Comment: can i ask you first? what is the result of this query when you execute it? `SELECT  COMPANY, PROJECT, MAX(TYPE) maxtype, MIN(TYPE) mintype
FROM    TABLE
GROUP   BY COMPANY, PROJECT`

Comment: I get both company A / project 2 and company A / project 3. Very weird.

Comment: here's the screenshot: [recordlist](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Rr8nJ.png), [query](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4vGHk.png), [result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cf8Mj.png)

Comment: `PROJECT` and `TYPE` are both reserved words.  It's hard to predict when reserved words will create problems.  With the sample data in a table named *tblProjects*, this version of JW's query gave me the results you want in Access 2007: `SELECT p.COMPANY, p.PROJECT FROM tblProjects AS p GROUP BY p.COMPANY, p.PROJECT HAVING Max(p.TYPE)=Min(p.TYPE) And Max(p.TYPE)='DUMMY';`

Comment: @HansUp even if they where reserved keyword, why did it also gave me correct results? see the screenshot :)

Comment: @JW. That is exactly why reserved words are maddening --- you can't predict when they will create problems.  Always safeguard against *any possibility* of trouble by prefixing those words with a table name or alias, or by enclosing them in square brackets.

Comment: Hi JW. I can understand why it does not work. Which MS Access version are you using? Is there another function we could use? I am hopeless. Thanks!

Comment: Hi JW. It worked! Thank you very much. I just figured out that even DUMMY projects had so called SUMMARY TASKS TYPE which were influencing the results. My bad and thank you very much!!!

Comment: honestly, I felt it weird because I tested in on Access 2003, 2007, and 2010 and it all worked. Then I was already thinking that there might be something missing or something was wrong with your data..hehe anyway, you're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `EXISTS` statement to get the answer you're looking for:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COMPANY, PROJECT
FROM TABLE t
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM TABLE tDummy
  WHERE tDummy.COMPANY = t.COMPANY
  AND tDummy.PROJECT = t.PROJECT
  AND tDummy.[TYPE] = 'DUMMY')
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM TABLE tNotDummy
  WHERE tNotDummy.COMPANY = t.COMPANY
  AND tNotDummy.PROJECT = t.PROJECT
  AND (
    tNotDummy.[TYPE] <> 'Dummy'
    OR tNotDummy.[TYPE] IS NULL));
```

This assumes that if `TYPE` is null, you don't count it as 'DUMMY'.